# Best solution to join multiple tables with variable columns for event attendance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, gridview

I have designed an Event Management System in which for each event the administrator has to add the attendance for each participant. The issue is that the event can have multiple session from 1 to infinite

Participants need to attend 80% of the session to be considered for the certificate.

The system is based on ASP.NET/C# with MS SQL 2012.
I have 6 tables involved, which are:

1. Events (for event information,column used: eventid)
2. Employees (for participant information, column used: employee name, employee department id)
3. Departments (Department information of Participants, column used: employee department id)
4. Participants (All participants for all events, column used: employeeid, eventid, Attended, Certified)
5. Session (Sessions Information for Events, column used: Session IDs)
6. Attendance (Attendance information for each employee for each session, column used: Attended)

Currently I am creating a table at runtime, by first getting all the registered participants of the event. Then running a loop for all registered participants and getting their department information and attendance information from the tables one by one.

Do keep in mind that for each session I am displaying a check box. So if the user is present in that session I mark it as check otherwise it is left as it is. The admin can then check uncheck the information against each registered participant and press save.

On save button again I read the entire table and put the information row by row for each user.

I feel that the solution is not very efficient, so I want to make it efficient. 
Also, administrators have issues in adding attendance because they cannot sort by name or department or id. Which will make it easier for them to add the attendance. They don't have select all option or unselect all option also.

So I want to know if there is any better solution using dynamic query or views.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here? If you want some help you need to provide details about your tables and an explanation of what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This topic is probably better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Apart from that without any code it's hard to recommend improvements for the specific cases of your "question".

Comment: No, it isn't. At least not as it is. Code Review requires working code to review.

Comment: I will add the code. I thought it will make the question quite long thats why i didnt add it in the first time. Will do it tomorrow.